# “the size of diagrams” or “the sizes of diagrams”

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> I have many diagrams with different sizes. I try to reduce the size of
>   each diagram.

Or:

> I reduce  the sizes of diagrams

Please tell me which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are possible. It depends on whether you want to suggest the action of 'reduce' is something you do once or many times. For example, you could say either:

> One step in my review process before I finalise a document is I reduce
>   the size of diagrams.
>
> One of the steps in my review process before I finalise a document is I reduce
>   the sizes of diagrams.

I apologise if that is confusing, but there is no definite answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry; native speakers have trouble with this one **all** the time. I know a song and the poor (native speaker) singer tries really hard to sing:
 "...When these kinds of questions..." 
but she just can't seem to remember and get over the natural tendency to say, "...**these kind** of questions..." which we hear every day..., and she gets so mixed up and sings it both ways throughout the song. Yes, it CAN sometimes be a little confusing, but I think you're already on the right track.

"**This** apple is red."  (no problem) 
"**These**" apples are red. (Still with me?)
"This is the kind I like!" (Still no problem?)
"These kinds are different from the red ones"

**If** the "**this**" or "**that**" is **singular**, then **so is** the "kind", "sort", "type", "example", "variety" etc.
If they are **plural**, so is the **word** they refer to:

"**These types** of boots bother my knees."
"**These examples** of ostriches are almost never found."

The reason we get confused is because **we're not** completely **sure** what the **subject** is.
If we know what the SUBJECT is, the VERB (and its number -plural or singular-) falls so easily into place, doesn't it?

"**These** **kinds** are wonderful!" (Subject="**KINDS** - ARE") Piece o' cake!
"**These kinds** of tomatoes are wonderful!" (STILL "kinds are") Nothing has changed except we added this little adjective prepositional phrase: (of what?) "of tomatoes", but "**KINDS**" **is** still **the subject**, isn't it?

Now I suppose someone MIGHT try to say "**These** **varieties** of tomato..." or "These types of fish..." and I wouldn't necessarily "throw the book" at them, but how much better it sounds when everything agrees: "These types of fishes..." ("Fish" has an exceptional "es" plural when it includes different varieties.)

Was that a help?